# Closing with "access denied" even with try-catch

Tags: c#, access-denied, readlines

I have a C# program that most of the time works fine, but sometimes closes because the file is used by another application. I would like my program to just ignore whenever this happens, so I'm using try-catch whenever I use File.Readlines, but this code still fails:

```
while (printerlinecount < Gvalue.LineCount)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string parameter = File.ReadLines(printerinfofile).Skip(printerlinecount).Take(1).First();
                        string parameterc = parameter.Trim(new Char[] { '[', ']' });
                        string printervalue = File.ReadLines(printerinfofile).Skip(printerlinecount + 2).Take(1).First();
                        string printervaluec = printervalue.Substring(6);
                        printerstatusvalues.Add(parameterc, printervaluec);
                        printerlinecount = printerlinecount + 4;
                    }

                    catch (IOException) { if (Settings.loglevel > 1) { Console.WriteLine("Access Denied (l)"); } }

                }
```

Anybody has an idea what I can do ?

best regards
Steen

Comment: What does "still fails" mean?

Comment: add a check, if the file is accessible, check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use

Comment: @MuhammadBashir I have tried this, but my application still closes when I use file.open this way. Try - Catch simply does not work for me and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to catch all exceptions, not only `IOException`:

```
catch (Exception)
```

Comment: Perhaps `UnauthorizedAccessException`?

Comment: @Enigmativity I explain why "code still fails". What will happen with `UnauthorizedAccessException` if file is missing?

Comment: Then you have another exception - however, it's easy to check if the file exists. It's almost always better to code around exceptions rather than let them rip. And you should only handle **specific** exceptions that you can **meaningfully** handle.

Comment: If I code review someone who writes `catch (Exception)`, I will send them back to fix the code. It's an awful pattern.

Comment: @Enigmativity What will happen without `catch (Exception)` - you prefer to see the default message box in unexpected cases? And what if reviewed code includes "most of the time works fine, but sometimes closes because the file is used by another application". Is it normal to handle this with try-catch?

Comment: "You prefer to see the default message box in unexpected cases?" Yes, but I prefer coders to code around exceptions so they never occur.

Comment: "And what if reviewed code includes "most of the time works fine, but sometimes closes because the file is used by another application". Is it normal to handle this with try-catch?" Yes, with the specific exception - not `catch (Exception)`.

Comment: I'm trying UnauthorizedAccessException, so far so good. The file is updated in this case, so missing file should not happen.